# Will alpha versions of apps in the Play Console produce crash reports?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm considering releasing an Alpha version of my app to a small group of testers. The Play console has the nice alpha-testing feature. I'm curious whether crashes these users encounter will also result in crash-reports being uploaded to the Play console?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They should be collected and uploaded just like any other application version.